# How to configure Nginx to work with html5mode

Tags: angularjs, nginx

For clean urls in angularjs I must use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` but when I refresh my page it shows a 404.

I've read that I need to configure server file.

**Structure**

```
 /html -
 /views -
   home.html
   about.html
   contact.html
 index.html
 app.js
```

What I've done so far:

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    root /html/views;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use server-side rendering of Angular?

Comment: @PhilipTzou Nope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Angular HTML5 location mode basically took advantage of HTML5 history API to "simulate" URL changes in client. But the URLs are probably not real (not exist) from the point of view from server therefore it's not possible to locate those pages on the server. There are generally two solutions can let server to know the URLs:

1. Use server-side rendering. This is widely used by another framework called ReactJS. And actually AngularJS 2.0 can work on a server too. Therefore it is possible to generate the real pages server-side and serve them to the client.
2. Use HTTP server rewrite techniques. This is what you are trying to do. The idea is to forward all related requests to a single AngularJS entrypoint HTML page, normally it's the `index.html` from the root.

For your case, assume the entrypoint of AngularJS is `/index.html`. Try this:

```
server {
    root /html/views;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

The previous solution is not perfect, because it will test every request arbitrarily. We can avoid unnecessary URL looking up by specify more detailed rules:

```
server {
    root /html/views;
    index index.html;

    rewrite "^/users" /index.html last;
    rewrite "^/pages" /index.html last;
    ...
}
```

Use regular expressions to match the URLs you want to serve with Angular.

Comment: where the "^/users"  and "^/pages" should I change that to home, about, contact, and the index.html part should be changed to the e.g. "^/about" /about.html?

Comment: @1bc: Your about page can be viewed by access `/views/about.html`. But if you want to access it by `/about/`, you should have `rewrite "^/about/?$" /views/about.html last;` in your rewriting rules. Also perhaps you should set `root` to `/html` but not `/html/views` according to your structure.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Do you have any other ideas to how to fix this issue?

Comment: My `index` was `htm` not `html`. I just needed to change the default root folder to my own folder and add  `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` inside `location / { }`