# html 5 mode in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have enabled HTML5 mode in my angular application.

It works fine when I start my application and navigate. However, when I hit reload in browser, it

```
Cannot GET /routename/
```

In my local system, it works fine with livereload block of grunt:

```
livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect, options,middleware) {
            var optBase = (typeof options.base === 'string') ? [options.base] : options.base;
            return [
              [require('connect-modrewrite')(['!(\\..+)$ / [L]'])].concat(
                optBase.map(function(path){ return connect.static(path); })),
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      }
```

However, it does not work on server.

Note: On server, it breaks only when I hit reload. Locally it works fine completely.

How do I fix this?

NOTE: I do have

```
app.get('*' ,(req,res,next) => req.sendFile('index.html'));
```

in `app.js` in NODE JS

Also, grunt is running the app on port 9000 and node sever is running on port 11000.

When it returns 404

```
Request URL:http://serverIP:9000/signUp/
```

It would not go to NodeJS server here.

Comment: You should configure your web server to work with html5 mode, for nginx see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112539/resolved-how-to-configure-nginx-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: @Anatoly: Added: app.get('*' ,(req,res,next) => req.sendFile('index.html'));
in app.js. But made no difference